# Match up to but not including string with multiple underscores

Tags: regex

I have a strings for example

```
Apple_Banana_Orange_PACK101_10
Pear_Apple__Grapes_BUNDLE222_06
```

I need a regex string that will match everything before _PACK or _BUNDLE and nothing else.

So for example I want the first string to return

```
Apple_Banana_Orange
```

I have tried:

If you're looking to capture everything up to "abc":

```
/^(.*?)(_PACK|_BUN)/
```

And a few other options but still struggling. Any help appreciated

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: In you pattern you are using 2 capturing groups and you already have your match in the first capturing group. See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0djl9B/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use Positive Lookahead as follows:

```
^.*?(?=_PACK|_BUN)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xp5YFo/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
^(.*)(_PACK|_BUNDLE)
```

where group 1 is what you want to catch